# column name alias to already existing column in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a dataframe with some columns as below. When I select some columns using alias to already existing column name, I don't get any error and I can no longer use those columns in the new dataframe

```
df1 = sc.parallelize([
    (1984-01-01, 1, 638.55),
    (1984-01-02, 2, 638.55)
]).toDF(["date1", "hour", "value1"])

# df1
# +----------+----+------+
# |     date1|hour|value1|
# +----------+----+------+
# |1984-01-01|   1|638.55|
# |1984-01-02|   2|638.55|
# +----------+----+------+
```

When I alias some column to already existing column as below, we can no longer get back the data from the dataframe

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as sf
new_df = df1.select(sf.col('date1').alias('hour'), sf.col('hour'))

# new_df
+----------+----+
|      hour|hour|
+----------+----+
|1984-01-01|   1|
|1984-01-02|   2|
+----------+----+
```

When I try to select "*hour*" column, it gives ambiguous column error

```
new_df.select('hour').show()

pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: "Reference 'hour' is ambiguous, could be: hour, hour.;"
```

How can I access the data now?

Comment: *When I try to select **"hour"** column* - which column do you mean? It's not only ambiguous to spark, it's ambiguous in your question. What are you trying to do? (What's the desired output?) Also, why would you rename a column to an existing column's name?

Comment: In real scenario, I will have hundreds of columns in my dataframe. So every time i select the columns by aliasing, I need to have a check if it is already existing in the aliased list.

Comment: checking is not hard, even with 100 columns it will be fast: `df1.select(sf.col('date1').alias('hour' + ("_" if "hour" in df1.columns else "")), sf.col('hour'))`

Comment: aliasing the column name could be dynamic as well. so we can't just check the existing columns. we need to check on all the alias names as well. What if I am trying to remove underscores `_` from all column names and there are 2 columns as `ho_ur` and `h_our`